# split a string into two based on a substring with all combinations

Tags: php

Let say I have a string:

```
$test = "Amy and Babel are good friends, they went to play together and Babel got hurt."
```

Now, lets say I want to split the string based on the word "Babel" (which occurred twice in this string)

My output should be stored in an array of arrays, with all possible combinations. For instance, in this case array element contains

- "Amy and" , "are good friends, they went to play together and Babel got hurt."
- "Amy and Babel are good friends, they went to play together and" , "Babel got hurt."

My initial attempt in to use `explode("Babel", $test)` to get all the relevant sub-strings. I am stuck with how to put them together in an efficient way.

Comment: I was unsure what is the most efficient way to get the result into a data structure I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$inputText = "Amy and Babel are good friends, Babel being the little rascal, they went to play together and Babel got hurt.";
$explodeString = "Babel";
$exploded = explode($explodeString, $inputText);
$resultArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($exploded)-1; ++$i) {
    $resultArray[$i] = array(implode($explodeString, array_slice($exploded, 0, $i+1)), implode($explodeString, array_slice($exploded, $i+1, (count($exploded)-1)-$i)));
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amy and 
        [1] =>  are good friends, Babel being the little rascal, they went to play together and Babel got hurt.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amy and Babel are good friends, 
        [1] =>  being the little rascal, they went to play together and Babel got hurt.
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Amy and Babel are good friends, Babel being the little rascal, they went to play together and 
        [1] =>  got hurt.
    )
)
```

Comment: Its relatively easy to read code, but there's definitely more optimized possibilities. For every increase of occurrences the explodeString has in the inputText, 2 more string join operations happen, that join the amount of strings equal to the amount of occurrences the explodeString has in the inputtext.

Answer (score 2):

This link may help you
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
<?php
$str = 'one|two|three|four';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

// negative limit (since PHP 5.1)
print_r(explode('|', $str, -1));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two|three|four
)
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

Comment: Explode is the answer yes, but as the OP already stated, they've already used it.

Comment: @AndyHolmes : OP is stucked on how to put it back together...that's actually a confusing line....put it back in string or `implode` back!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I want the result to be stored in an array, where each element of the array it-self is an array containing one possible combination in which the the string is split into 2 substrings.